# Is it possible to have covariates for different tasks within an split-plot analysis?

Tags: experiment-design, predictor, split-plot

I am conducting an experiment which looks at between-within subjects. There are two groups (participants will either use an iphone and android in the experiment) and they both have 4 short tasks to complete which will look at speed of completion. I am using split-plot/ mixed-design anova.

Before they completed the tasks, they were asked if they had any experience of what each task was using (e.g. sending a voice recording, surfing the internet, etc.) I was going to put the answers as a covariate to account for participants baseline for each task.

Is it possible to have covariates set for each individual task during the analysis or can you only set covariates as a baseline for the whole experiment?